# Tex Gyre showcase

Tags: fonts

I have a simple question: Is there an available document that would compare (showcase) all the fonts of the TeX Gyre collection? I supposed that something like this existed on the project homepage: http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre However, I did not manage to find anything like this there.

Is there a simple way how to get such a thing every time I want to choose a font for my works, or do I have to create it myself only to lose it before I need it again?

Comment: You mean other than the font catalogue?

Comment: @cfr Well, in the catalogue, you have to click on each separate font, you can display all of them next to each other in some nice way, including the variants. That's what I miss.

Comment: Actually, it would be nice to have better font cataloguing of TeX fonts in general.

Comment: However, if you do create it yourself, you can always post it here as an answer so that you can find it in the future ;).

Comment: @cfr What a crazy idea! However, it seems that the file exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the showcase exists, it is just not part of the document that opens on `texdoc tex-gyre`. It can be found here:

http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/tex-gyre/doc/fonts/tex-gyre/qag-test.pdf

It shows all `tg` fonts in all variants, as far as I see.

Comment: `texdoc qag-test` works though (on my tl2014 setup at least)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It does, but who I am to remember that? :p